# How do you make an eternal night world using mystcraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-mystcraft

I've searched the FTB wiki and many other sites and have yet to find out how to make a world that has eternal night. Any help?

Comment: There a portal to the twilight forest but im unsure if thats a mod and which one.

Comment: Time night or no sun night?

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Dark Sun" symbol. Or else "Nadir", "Zero Length", "Normal Sun".

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Make a clock connected to a command block with the command: `time set 15000`

This will keep setting the time to 12:30 AM in Minecraft time. To restore the day-night cycle, destroy the clock.

2. Wait for it to become night time, then do the command `/gamerule doDaylightCycle false`. To restore the day-night cycle, do the command `/gamerule doDaylightCycle true`

Hope this helps! :)